# Not able to debug JS under source tab with webpack 2

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, bundling-and-minification, webpack-2

I start my webpack-sev-server with following npm cmd:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port 8090 --open -d --inline --output-pathinfo"
```

In my webpack config I also have:

```
devtool: 'source-map'
```

but as I understand this is irrelevant since the -d option will set devtool to sourcemap anyway.

Once running I can see the individual JS files under the sources tab (Chrome):
[image]

But it does not seem to serve more purpose than dimple documentation. If I click on an error in the console it will still point my to the bundled (unreadable) JS file. Also the browser will not break on any breakpoint in those JS files.

I'm a bit new to this so probably I'm missing something obvious here but I can't find it...

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour can be related to the following webpack's issue: [[HELP WANTED] Perform source-map audit against webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3165).

Please, try to use `cheap-module-source-map`. See [Inline Source Map Types](https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/source-maps/#inline-source-map-types) section of webpack documentation about Source Maps.

Also, I recommend place dev-server options in the configuration file under the `devServer` key, because CLI arguments override options in the configuration file.

Hope it helps.